# Mq upgrade from 8.0 to 9.3 in midvision server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-mq

We have a requirement to upgrade midvision mq server 8.0 version to 9.3 version in midvision MQ server. I have no idea how we can upgrade it. Any step by step guide

Kindly suggest me the steps how we can upgrade with the minimal downtime

Answer (score 0):

I used Google to search on your question and the first hit was [IBM MQ Migration paths](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=mq-migration-paths).

And the instructions for doing it are [Upgrading IBM MQ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=migrating-upgrading-mq)